# Check query results if no data is returned

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query that I am calling to update an email service.  Most times it will have data in it, but in testing I came across the situation of it not returning any data because there was no data to return.  In the case of no data it returns the error "Variable EDITEDACCTS is undefined".

I have tried wrapping the query in a `<cftry>` but it doesn't "fail" per se so it does not trip the `<cfcatch>`.  I have also tried defining the variable

`var EditedAccts = QueryNew("")`

as well as simply trying

`<cfif NOT isDefined(#EditedAccts#)>`

and it always returns "Variable EDITEDACCTS is undefined".
I need a production ready solution to this and I'm hoping somewhere here on SO can help me out.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do not use # signs with IsDefined(). It causes evaluation of `EditedAccts` which triggers the very error you are trying to prevent. Is this a basic select query? Because the query object itself should still exist even if it does not contain any records.

Comment: .. forgot to include the correct syntax for isDefined: `<cfif NOT isDefined("EditedAccts")>`

Comment: Thanks @Leigh.  Removing the # signs worked.  I figured it was something simple but I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: @JimP - Good. So what kind of sql statement are you running? Like I mentioned a `SELECT` query should always exist. Just wondering if you ran into a possible bug or are misunderstanding cfquery.

Comment: @Leigh - It's a `SELECT` statement with a couple of nested queries but it was simply a misunderstanding on my part of `isDefined()` as a function.  A perfect example of how awesome SO can be when you just aren't catching the obvious error in front of you.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @JimP - Not to belabor the point, but you should not need to use `IsDefined` with `SELECT` queries. So it is *possible* you encountered a bug. But glad everything is working now :)

Comment: @Leigh - That's fine.  I can look into it more later but I'm working against a release date.  But just for future reference for you and for anyone else interested I actually applied my solution below and then test the records returned and then proceed from that point because `isDefined()` as well as `isQuery()` aren't specific enough for my needs.  Thanks again for everything. Cheers!

Comment: @JimP - Sounds good. Best of luck with the release :) Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found the answer.  You set the "result" parameter in the query call and then you can check the recordcount field returned.

```
<cfquery name="EditedAccts" datasource="mydatasource" result="queryResult">
    ...query goes here...
</cfquery>
```

When using the "result" parameter you get a struct returned with the sql used, the cached setting, the execution time and the record count. 
Now I can check the record count and proceed from there.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: The query result itself has a recordcount property.  `#ecitAccts.recordcount#` will give you the same result.  And as Leigh said on your original post, a zero-record resultset does NOT result in an exception, and is still defined.

Comment: *Edit* Is it possible your cfquery contains something other than a `SELECT` statement, like an `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using result="queryResult" but when I tried to reference the query name I got something like this error - "The value of the attribute query, which is currently EditedAccts, is invalid".  Instead, I used something like IsDefined("#EditedAccts#") - including the value in quotes did the trick for me.  I am only new to ColdFusion but I am learning quickly that values in quotes are entirely different to values not in quotes, in terms of how a function will interpret a parameter.

Comment: Well it is really on a case by case basis. In theory, SELECT's should *always* return a query object. Unless something is interfering... like if the query contains multiple sql statements, so we would need to see the actual query. As an aside, do not use # signs with isDefined. That function expects the *name* of a variable, ie a string. As I mentioned [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379730/check-query-results-if-no-data-is-returned#comment7473686_6379730), using # signs means causes the variable to be evaluated, triggering the very error you are trying to prevent :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I didn't test with # and I wasn't sure if that was the correct syntax (which is why I said, something like) - I actually used IsDefined("insertQueryNameHere"). I thought the query was pretty straight forward, along the lines of `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1_id = table2_id WHERE criteria order by col1` so not sure why the query object was not returned.

Comment: Yes, I figured the real code did not have # signs or it would have failed. Just wanted to mention the correct syntax for IsDefined, since using # signs is a common gotcha :)  From the description, the statement sounds okay, but again it all depends on the *exact* query, environment, query scope, etcetera.